# Does this "linear-approximated" version of Graph Counting Lemma hold?

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory, extremal-graph-theory, extremal-combinatorics

Let $0\leq d\ll\varepsilon,\frac{1}{e},\frac{1}{v}\leq 1.$ Let $G$ be a $n$-vertices graph ($n$ is sufficient large, $1/n\ll d$) and for any $A,B\subseteq V(G)$, the edge density $d(A,B)\geq d.$ Then for any $v$-vertices $e$-edges graph $H$, we have:
$$t(H,G)\geq \varepsilon d^{e}.$$
Notice that the density $``d"$ is very little compared with the error term $``\varepsilon"$. And consider $1/n\ll d$ it is still a dense graph. When $\varepsilon\ll d$, it holds $t(H,G)\geq  d^{e}-e\varepsilon.$

Thank you for your attention for this question.

Moreover, if this is wrong, let $H$ bipartite leads this right?